# Android threading - repeat group of threads a few times with delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading, queue

I am going to implement an application that is gathering data from Android device.

Here is what I have right now:

- Main activity with a button **Run**
- Button starts a **Recorder**
- **Recorder** has 4 *Resources* that are *Runnable*

  - GpsResource
  - ImageResource
  - AudioResource
  - GyroscopeResource
- In *Recorder* there is a *for* loop (for example `i < 3`) that runs pack of threads with some delay (`i * 5000`)

How should I create that threads so all of them will start simultaneously (`i=0`), then after 5 seconds start again (`i=1`) and after next 5 seconds again (`i=2`) ?

Next thing:

Every resource returns some data with `getData()` method - simplify it - string with random characters. How to notify in **Recorder** that all threads in queue are completed and gather all data from resources ?

The last thing:

I have to be able after creating all that queues to stop executing all threads. Example:

We have a 7th second, 2nd queue is running now and user clicks a button **Stop**. Queue with running threads is going to complete, but next queues will not start, just **Recodred** has to forget about them.

I tried to write as simple as possible, I believe that you guys understand me.

Thanks for any advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea to solve at least one part of the question:

To start resources together and wait for them to complete:

Take a `CompletionService`:

```
Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CompletionService<String> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(e);
CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
for (int i=0; i<numberOfResources; i++) {
     Resource r = createResource(startLatch, i);
     service.submit(r);
}
startLatch.countDown();
```

`Resource` should look something like this:

```
class Resource implements Callable<String> { 
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    public Resource(CountDownLatch latch) { this.latch = latch; }
    public String call() throws Exception {
        latch.await();
        return getData();
    }
}
```

Not to get the data back from the completion service:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfResources; i++) {
    String data = service.take().get();
    // do something with data
}
```

Please note that this is more of pseudo-code, not actually tested :)

And there are still open questions what would you do if some resource takes more than 5 seconds to execute. Another one is to schedule the same operations every 5 seconds.